# Is it possible to delete or move a drawn object among some other overlaped drawn objects in GDI+?

Tags: oop, visual-c++, graphics, c++-cli, gdi+

I am trying to draw some geometric objects on canvas which may overlap each others in an ordered they have been drawn in VC++.net (or VC#). It is simply done by drawing Rectangle or other related drawing methods in order. But the problem comes up when I try to move or delete one specific object between the overlapped ordered objects without affecting the appearance of other ordered overlap object! this is seems to be related to the concept of Object Oriented Programming for graphic programming which I expect to be doable in GDI+ but I couldn't find any related methods to do things like that. can anyone help how can I do this in GDI+ ?

Comment: You have to redraw the invalidated area.

Comment: how can I find the invalid area ?! are all drawn objects available in an array or vector from graphic class?

Comment: Once drawn, your objects just become pixels, nothing more. They're not retained objects, GDI+ uses immediate mode graphics. You can determine the invalid area based on the area of the shape you want to *"delete"*, and you need to remember that information yourself.

Comment: so in ms windows, when u drag a window over some other windows, just the overlapped area is redrawn and i am not sure windows redraw all of the affected abject! based on this fact, i guess some mechanism should exist that redraw the shaded area automatically after dragging or deleting on object !